# What is the sequence of numbers for N = 6?

Tags: algorithms, logic-programming

[image]

The numbers in the table below are the result of executing an algorithm that has one parameter N, a non-negative integer, and produces sequences of integers as outputs. For values of N from 0 to 5, the algorithm produces the following sequences of numbers as outputs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a puzzle rather than a technical question.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one possible algorithm:

- If $N = 0$, output the empty string.
- If $N = 1$, output "0 1".
- If $N = 2$, output "0 2 2 3".
- If $N = 3$, output "0 2 4 3 4 5".
- If $N = 4$, output "0 2 4 6 4 5 6 7".
- If $N = 5$, output "0 2 4 6 8 5 6 7 8 9".
- Otherwise, output the empty string.

Now, this is probably not the answer they were expecting, but it's perfectly valid.

(The answer they expected was: output the first $N$ even integers starting with zero, and then the first $N$ integers starting with $N$.)

Comment: answer of the sequence

Comment: Trick question $\Rightarrow$ trick answer!

Comment: I was about to say the same thing! These kind of "problems" are really annoying. There is literally a countable infinity of algorithms that produce that same output. Why should one be preferred (notice that it says "determine **the** algorithm that was used [...]"?